# Xcode - Web services and my confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, web-services

I am having a problem here. I am totally new to this concept of servers and web services and being able to get data uploaded and retrieved on different devices, but I want to learn it, say if I want to create an app like Instagram.

But that is EXACTLY what I dont want, a link to a **long** tutorial on the internet on how to create the most complex app ever, I want to start slow. After doing extensive power searches on Amazon there are basically no books that will help me. So I want to start slow, here is my **goal**:

*Get a great understanding of how web service backends and servers work and be able to apply it in other app ideas I have and want to start developing*

I would like to start by being able to create an app that allows a user to enter some text into a field, it uploads to the server, another device can press a button to retrieve the text and display it in a text view.

I do not know php, and every single tutorial I have entered on this website is literal mindeff, the reason for this is because **everyone** has a different solution, sync web service backend with Core Data, MySQL, parse, Rails and it **truly** overwhelms me because I do not know which one to pick! And even worse some people provide code but I have **no** understanding whatsoever, and its like looking at a totally new language!

I am not asking for code, in fact that is the exact opposite. I am asking for someone to really lay out their knowledge, how does it all work? What is the best tool? Some resources and links. Nothing too complex...

I hope you can truly understand my extreme confusion and frustration. I think the reason might be is I might not be ready yet for all this, but I want to push forward and carry out my app idea!

Thank you...

Update:

I have **finally** decided on a web service I would like to use, it is the Amazon S3 web service, I am still not fully comprehending the full process though, any help or ideas!?

Comment: Two things:  S3 is a web service that only stores objects on the web.  There isn't any programming or even a server that you can write code for.  There are just "buckets" to store information in and retrieve them.  That being said, it would be a good learning experience to figure out how to *interact* with an existing webservice before you worry about your own.  Secondly, check out the book "REST in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Architecture". It starts with much more fundamental information than most of the other books and describes the web's layout as well as lots of programming examples.

Comment: @Inafziger Thats what I want, to store objects on the web service and being able to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted to create an Instagram-type app, look at this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

This is a good link to servers: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC71D7CFB6AF935E6&feature=plcp. Watch the list to get an understanding of servers.

Maybe you want to read up on sql. Understanding sql will help.. Again: http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC32BC9C878BA72085&feature=plcp. Watch the list to get an understanding of sql...

I can pass you the link and you got to do the work....

Hope this helps...

Comment: If you properly read the question you will see that is exactly what I don't want!

Comment: nobody is going to spoon feed you... you got to try things yourself. read up things on your own.. and face problems in that paste here to get solutions...

Comment: the one i passed u is one very good website... please try... it will really help...

Comment: this will start you off... ask the specific qns here, and they will definitely help you... vague qns will not bring an answer....